# Is there a way to cache the multiple select menus which are populated from the database

Tags: php, caching

I have a big form with 132 (12x11) select menus which are populated from the db (MySQL). The problem is obvious: page takes a long time to load because of all those db calls.

The structure of the form:  there is a 12 separate sections each for 1 room with 11 dropdowns each (here is the link http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=6tfjpk&s=7).

From 11 of those dropdowns 8 are the same "Room Description".  Is there a way....I could somehow cache those dropdowns especially those 8 from the section 1 (room 1) and then just reload the cache for all other sections (other 11)? 
I tried to make the array in the function (which creates the dropdown from the database) with dynamic variables assigned to be static
    static ${$var_name};

but php parser itself doesn't allow dynamic variables to be static.

Comment: What stops you from saving these into an ini file? Or a flat file that you can just call later when your cache time expires

Comment: I'd look at the query before caching. Performance follows the 80/20 rule. That is to say optimizing the query may be quicker/easier than setting up caching.

Comment: @jakub I could do that ... but then what I should do when I update the database(I have to update the ,ini file again?)

Comment: @Jason the query is simple "select name from description" the problem is that I have 132 of them and 96 are the same queries...

Comment: What stops you from grabbing all the select fields (sorted) in 1 SQL query? Is it your schema?  You could grab them from an array depending on your need...

Comment: 132 queries sounds crazy. If 96 of those are the same, are you actually querying the database all 96 times? Why not query once and store that into an array and use the array 96 times? Honestly, I think we need to see some code to figure out if there is a better way to do this. Can't tell much from what you are describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved!**

@AJ

1. 1st part of the solution was to save the arrays from query into the session (AJ's recommendations). It helped, but not a lot (not as much as I expected saved me only 0.5 sec of page load.  Page was loading  before in 4,79 seconds afters this implementation... in 4,47sec's.
2. This part is an actual solution.

at the beginning of my code in **dorpdown function** I had this code:
`$dbh   =   new PDO(CONFIG_MYSQL_DSN, CONFIG_MYSQL_USERNAME, CONFIG_MYSQL_PASSWORD, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false));`

`$dbh   ->  setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

which means that **I was creating a new db connection every time the function has been called**. I made when I created the function some time ago and it was supposed to be used only for testing purposes because I actually have include file on every page which is making sure I'm connected to the database. It has an option `array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true`.

So, in order to avoid making db connection every time the dropdown function has been called I've set the $dbh to global`global $dbh;` in that include file. I've also set `global $dbh;` **in the function itself**. Now page is loading in ONLY 0.6 seconds instead of 4.76 what is a GREAT IMPROVEMENT!

Answer (score 0):

Why not save the arrays to your [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php)?